# Why does the compiler generate unchecked warnings when using TableColumn<S, T> rather than TableColumn<S, ?> to select a cell in a JavaFX8 TableView?

Tags: javafx, compiler-errors, javafx-8

A relative Java newbie question.

I'm cleaning up my code and came across two unchecked warnings ("*unchecked method invocation*" and "*unchecked conversion*") while programmatically selecting a cell in a `TableView`.  I was able to resolve the warnings but don't understand what caused them.

This was how I initially coded the `select()`:

```
TablePosition<?, ?> previousPos;
//...
table.getSelectionModel().select
    (previousPos.getRow(), previousPos.getTableColumn());
```

and I resolved the warnings by changing it to this.

```
table.getSelectionModel().select
    (previousPos.getRow(), table.getColumns().get(previousPos.getColumn()));
```

I didn't understand the difference so I had a look at the Java source code. If I'm interpreting it correctly, the `select()` method in *TableView.java* expects `TableColumn<S, ?>`. However, `getTableColumn()` in *TablePosition.java* returns `TableColumn<S,T>` while `getColumns()` in *TableView.java* returns an `ObservableList` of type `TableColumn(S, ?)`.

I guess that's why `table.getColumns().get(...)` compiles clean and `previousPos.getTableColumn()` generates errors.

But what is the difference, then, between `TableColumn<S, ?>` and `TableColumn<S,T>` from the compiler's point of view? Why doesn't it resolve (is that the correct term?) the `T` to `?`.

If it helps, here is the MVCE I was playing with to try and figure it out, but the answer is beyond my current Java knowledge.  The `select()` is in `moveToPreviousPos()`.

I'm using JavaFX8 (JDK1.8.0_181), NetBeans 8.2 and Scene Builder 8.3.

```
package test27;

import javafx.application.Application;
import static javafx.application.Application.launch;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TablePosition;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.TextFieldTableCell;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Test27 extends Application {

    TableView<TestModel> table = new TableView<>();

    //Both of these stop the "unchecked conversion" error on line #51 (previousPos = table.getFocusModel().getFocusedCell();)
    //    TablePosition previousPos;
        TablePosition<?, ?> previousPos;
    //but using the following generates the "unchecked conversion" error
    //    TablePosition<TestModel, ?> previousPos;

    private Parent createContent() {

        ObservableList<TestModel> olTestModel = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

        olTestModel.add(new TestModel("A"));
        olTestModel.add(new TestModel("B"));
        olTestModel.add(new TestModel("C"));

        table.setItems(olTestModel);

        TableColumn<TestModel, String> colText = new TableColumn<>("text");
        colText.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().textProperty());
        colText.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());

        table.getSelectionModel().setCellSelectionEnabled(true);
        table.setEditable(true);
        table.getColumns().add(colText);

        Button btnGetTablePosition = new Button("get table position");
        btnGetTablePosition.setOnAction(event -> {
            //TableView.java:  getFocusedCell returns TablePosition<S, ?>
            previousPos = table.getFocusModel().getFocusedCell(); //Line #51
            outputPreviousPos(previousPos);
        });

        Button btnMoveToPreviousPos = new Button("move to previous pos");
        btnMoveToPreviousPos.setOnAction(event -> {
            moveToPreviousPos(previousPos);
        });

        BorderPane content = new BorderPane(table);
        HBox hb = new HBox();
        hb.getChildren().addAll(btnGetTablePosition, btnMoveToPreviousPos);

        content.setTop(hb);

        return content;

    }

    public void outputPreviousPos(TablePosition previousPos){

        System.out.println("previousPos = " + previousPos);

    }

    public void moveToPreviousPos(TablePosition previousPos) {

        //select() in TableView.java expects TableColumn<S, ?>
        //getTableColumn() in TablePosition.java returns TableColumn<S,T>
        //getColumns() in TableView.java returns an ObservableList of type TableColumn(S, ?)

        //Is that why the following line generates  "unchecked method invocation" and "unchecked conversion" errors
        //table.getSelectionModel().select
        //      (previousPos.getRow(), previousPos.getTableColumn());
        //but the following line compiles clean?
        table.getSelectionModel().select
                (previousPos.getRow(), table.getColumns().get(previousPos.getColumn()));        

    }

    public class TestModel {

        private StringProperty text;

        public TestModel() {
            this("");
        }

        public TestModel(
            String text
        ) {
            this.text = new SimpleStringProperty(text);
        }

        public String getText() {
            return text.get();
        }

        public void setText(String text) {
            this.text.set(text);
        }

        public StringProperty textProperty() {
            return text;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        stage.setScene(new Scene(createContent()));
        stage.setTitle("Test");
        stage.setWidth(500);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, I would say that it was a design flaw that `TableView.getFocusModel().getFocusedCell()` (or `focusedCellProperty()`) uses the raw `TablePosition` type (raw `TablePosition` can only be cast to `TablePositon<?, ?>` without generating warning). The more suitable version could have been `TablePosition<S, ?>`.

Since `TablePosition` represents a particular cell *anywhere* in the `TableView`, then for `TableView.getFocusModel().focusedCellProperty()`:

1. The type of `S` is fixed for `TableView<S>` (i.e. the type is known).
2. The type of `T` refers to the type of a *particular* `TableColumn`, which can change depending on which cell has been focused. You cannot determine the type at compile time because you have no idea which `TableColumn<S, T>` would be selected.

Now to the second point.

> But what is the difference, then, between `TableColumn<S, ?>` and
>   `TableColumn<S,T>` from the compiler's point of view? Why doesn't it
>   resolve (is that the correct term?) the `T` to `?`.

This is because `?` in `TableColumn<S, ?>` is a wildcard. Since `TableViewFocusModel<S>` does not have the type `T` and that it does not operate based on a fixed column, so it has to use `?` here (see the first point that I explained).

On the other hand, `TableView.getSelectionModel().select()` expects an `int` for `row` and a `TableColumn<S, ?>` for column. Since you had `TablePosition<?, ?> previousPos`, so  `previousPos` would return a `TableColumn<?, ?>` as well. `TableColumn<S, ?` and `TableColumn<?, ?>` are very different - you could use the `TableColumn` from another `TableView` if `TableColumn<?, ?>` is allowed.

Finally, if the API for `TableView.getFocusModel().getFocusedCell()` is fixed, then there would not be a problem when you use `select()`. Until then, you could manually cast it to `TablePosition<TestModel, ?>` with a suppression, or use `TableView.getColumns().get(index)` like what you did.

Comment: Thanks very much for your explanation, Jai.  I think I understand it now.  Your reply may also help me fix some other warnings that have got me puzzled.  For the moment, I won't suppress compiler errors.  If nothing else, it's teaching me more about Java and is forcing me to write (hopefully!) cleaner code. :-)

Comment: Well, I like people who probes into why something happens certain way. I think programming is more than "it doesn't work now, please make it work." On another note, you could probably report `TableView.getFocusModel().focusedCellProperty()` issue to [Oracle](http://bugreport.java.com/).

Comment: Thank you.  And likewise, I appreciate people who give their time to help those of us who really do want to learn. :-)  Re reporting the issue to Oracle.  I don't think my knowledge is yet robust enough to write a plausible case, but I will set it aside for future.  Cheers for now.