# How to get a TableColumn of type <S, T> from a TableView's focus model in JavaFX8 and still get a clean compile?

Tags: generics, javafx, tableview, javafx-8, compiler-warnings

Another relative Java newbie question.

I'm cleaning up my code and am down to the last two compiler issues.  Both relate to needing to get a `TableColumn` of type `<S, T>` from a call to `tableView.getFocusModel().getFocusedCell()`.  I'm getting compiler warnings and haven't yet been able to resolve them.

I think the warnings stem from a `TableView`'s focus model's use of a raw `TablePosition` type and, if I'm understanding the implications correctly, it means that any `TableColumn` based on the `TablePosition` returned from a call to `tableView.getFocusModel().getFocusedCell()` *has* to be declared as a *raw* type in order for the code to compile cleanly.

IE.  if I do this:

```
TablePosition pos = tableView.getFocusModel().getFocusedCell();
```

then I will only ever get a clean compile if I do this:

```
TableColumn col = pos.getTableColumn();
```

*TablePosition.java* in the Java documentation says that `pos.getTableColumn()` returns `TableColumn<S,T>` and I guess it can't do that if the focus model is returning a raw `TablePosition` type.  I understand that.

But, **if I then have to declare a `TableColumn` as raw, how can I "convert" it to type `<S, T>` (or work around the generics?) such that I end up with `TableColumn<S, T>` and still get a clean compile**?  Once I know that, I will hopefully be able to fix the last two compiler issues.

I experimented with the accepted answer in [How to work around Java generic wildcard limitations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35392063/how-to-work-around-java-generic-wildcard-limitations) and while that works, suppressing compiler errors isn't what I want to do.  I also tried using the `TableView`'s selection model rather than the focus model but it seems that `table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedCells().get(0)` returns a raw `TablePosition`, too. The focus model's use of raw `TablePosition` was explained by user Jai in the reply to an earlier question I asked [Why does the compiler generate unchecked warnings when using TableColumn<S, T> rather than TableColumn<S, ?> to select a cell in a JavaFX8 TableView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52693823/why-does-the-compiler-generate-unchecked-warnings-when-using-tablecolumns-t-r)).

If if helps, here is the MVCE I was playing with to try and resolve the last two compiler issues.  Both relate to needing to get a `TableColumn` of type `<S, T>` in each of the `getFocussedColumn()` and `getGraphic()` methods. I've left my comments in so you can see what I've tried.  Also, in order to reproduce the issues, the MVCE had to use the custom checkbox cell that my app uses.  I've pruned it as much as I can to keep it as "M" as possible.

I'm using JavaFX8 (JDK1.8.0_181), NetBeans 8.2 and Scene Builder 8.3.

I'm compiling with "-Xlint:unchecked".

```
package test28;

import java.util.function.BiConsumer;
import java.util.function.Function;
import javafx.application.Application;
import static javafx.application.Application.launch;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.beans.property.BooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleBooleanProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox;
import javafx.scene.control.ContentDisplay;
import javafx.scene.control.TableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TablePosition;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.ToggleGroup;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Test28 extends Application {

    static TableView<TestModel> table = new TableView<>();
    ToggleGroup tgRadios = new ToggleGroup();

    private Parent createContent() {

        ObservableList<TestModel> olTestModel = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

        olTestModel.add(new TestModel(false));
        olTestModel.add(new TestModel(true));
        olTestModel.add(new TestModel(false));

        table.setItems(olTestModel);
        Platform.runLater(() -> table.getSelectionModel().selectFirst());

        //Column with a custom cell that renders as a CheckBox
        TableColumn<TestModel, Boolean> colCheckbox = createCheckBoxColumn("checkbox", TestModel::checkboxProperty, TestModel::setCheckbox);

        table.getSelectionModel().setCellSelectionEnabled(true);
        table.setEditable(true);
        table.getColumns().add(colCheckbox);

        Button btnGetFocussedCol = new Button("get focussed col");
        btnGetFocussedCol.setOnAction(event -> {
            TableColumn<TestModel, Boolean> col = getFocussedColumn();
            System.out.println("col = " + col);
        });

        Button btnGetGraphic = new Button("get graphic");
        btnGetGraphic.setOnAction(event -> {
            Node node = getGraphic();
            System.out.println("node = " + node);
        });

        BorderPane content = new BorderPane(table);
        HBox hb = new HBox();
        hb.setPadding(new Insets(10,10,10,10));
        hb.setSpacing(20.0);
        hb.getChildren().addAll(btnGetFocussedCol, btnGetGraphic);

        content.setTop(hb);

        return content;

    }

    //*************************************************************************************
    //First of two remaining compiler issues to resolve

    private static <S, T> TableColumn<S, T> getFocussedColumn() {

        //getFocusedCell() returns a RAW TablePosition
        TablePosition pos = table.getFocusModel().getFocusedCell();

        //pos.getTableColumn() should be returning TableColumn<S,T>, however, pos is a RAW type
        //so I guess that's why I'm getting an unchecked conversion warning on the following line
        //TableColumn<S, T> col = pos.getTableColumn();

        //Casting it generates an unchecked cast warning
        //TableColumn<S, T> col = (TableColumn<S, T>) pos.getTableColumn();

        //Using a RAW TableColumn type fixes the warnings on the TableColumn declaration
        //but generates an unchecked conversion warning on the "return col" line
        TableColumn col = pos.getTableColumn();

        //table.getColumns() returns ObservableList<TableColumn<S,?>>, so I cannot use the following
        //TableColumn<S, T> col = table.getColumns().get(pos.getColumn());

        //getFocusedCell().getTableColumn() returns TableColumn<S,?>, so I cannot do the following
        //return table.getFocusModel().getFocusedCell().getTableColumn();

        //unchecked conversion warning generated on this line when TableColumn is raw
        //==> HOW CAN I "CONVERT" A RAW TABLECOLUMN TO TABLECOLUMN<S, T>?
        return col;

    }

    //*************************************************************************************
    //Second of two remaining compiler issues to resolve

    public <S, T> Node getGraphic() {

        TablePosition pos = table.getFocusModel().getFocusedCell();

        //Declaring TableColumn as a raw type generates an "unchecked call to call(P) as a member of the raw type Callback"
        //warning on the TableCell declaration below
        TableColumn col = pos.getTableColumn();

        //getCellFactory().call() expects CellDataFeatures<S,T> and returns ObservableValue<T>
        //unchecked call to call(P) warning generated on this line when TableColumn is raw
        //==> HOW CAN I "CONVERT" A RAW TABLECOLUMN TO TABLECOLUMN<S, T>?
        TableCell cell = (TableCell) col.getCellFactory().call(col);

        Node cellGraphic = cell.getGraphic();
        return cellGraphic;

    }

    //*************************************************************************************
    //Create a custom checkbox

    public <S> TableColumn<S, Boolean> createCheckBoxColumn(String title, 
            Function<S, BooleanProperty> methodGetCheckBoxFieldProperty, 
            BiConsumer<? super S, ? super Boolean> methodSetCheckBoxField) {

        TableColumn<S, Boolean> col = new TableColumn<>(title);

        col.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> methodGetCheckBoxFieldProperty.apply(cellData.getValue()));

        col.setCellFactory(column -> CheckBoxCell.createCheckBoxCell());

        col.setOnEditCommit(event -> {
            Boolean masterCode = event.getNewValue();
            S dataModel = event.getRowValue();
            methodSetCheckBoxField.accept(dataModel, masterCode);
        });

        return col;

    }

    //*************************************************************************************
    //The custom CheckBoxCell class

    public static class CheckBoxCell<S, T> extends TableCell<S, T> {

        private final CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox();

        public CheckBoxCell() {

            setGraphic(checkBox);
            setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY);

        }

        public static <S> CheckBoxCell<S, Boolean> createCheckBoxCell() {
            return new CheckBoxCell<S, Boolean>();
        }

        @Override
        protected void updateItem(T item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);
            if (empty) {
                setGraphic(null);
            } else {
                setText( ((Boolean) item).toString());
                checkBox.setSelected( (Boolean) item);
                setGraphic(checkBox);
                setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY);
            }
        }

    }    

    //*************************************************************************************

    public class TestModel {

        private BooleanProperty checkbox;

        public TestModel() {
            this(false);
        }

        public TestModel(
            boolean checkbox
        ) {
            this.checkbox = new SimpleBooleanProperty(checkbox);
        }

        public boolean getCheckbox() {
            return checkbox.get();
        }

        public void setCheckbox(boolean checkbox) {
            this.checkbox.set(checkbox);
        }

        public BooleanProperty checkboxProperty() {
            return checkbox;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        stage.setScene(new Scene(createContent()));
        stage.setTitle("Test");
        stage.setWidth(500);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi again. For a start, you can cast it like this: `TablePosition<TestModel, ?> pos = (TablePosition<TestModel, ?>) tableView.getFocusModel().getFocusedCell()`. Most of the things after that, if not everything, should flow on naturally with `<TestModel, ?>`.

Comment: You just have to use the `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` annotation on that single time, and most likely everything will fall in place at the later part. You probably have to live with this as this is the API flaw.

Comment: Hi again, Jai.  Thanks for that.  I had tried `TablePosition<S, ?> pos = (TablePosition<S, ?>) table.getFocusModel().getFocusedCell();` and got an unchecked cast warning.  If there's no way around it, I will use @SuppressWarnings("unchecked").  I just thought I was missing something really fundamental.  Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to user Jai's help, the answer is that the only way of getting a `TableColumn<S, T>` from a call to `tableView.getFocusModel().getFocusedCell();` AND getting a clean compile is to use the `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` annotation.

This is because:

1. The `TableView` API is written to return a raw `TablePosition` type  from `getFocusedCell()`.
2. There *is* no way to "convert" a raw type into a `<S, T>` (or any other) type.  They are very different things.

So, the compiler issues highlighted in the MVCE in my question were solved like this:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked") 
private static <S, T> TableColumn<S, T> getFocussedColumnx() {
    TablePosition<S, T> pos = (TablePosition<S, T>) table.getFocusModel().getFocusedCell();
    TableColumn<S, T> col = (TableColumn<S, T>) pos.getTableColumn();
    return col;
}
```

and this:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public <S, T> Node getGraphic() {
    TablePosition<S, T> pos = (TablePosition<S, T>) table.getFocusModel().getFocusedCell();
    TableColumn<S, T> col = (TableColumn<S, T>) pos.getTableColumn();
    TableCell<S, T> cell = (TableCell<S, T>) col.getCellFactory().call(col);
    Node cellGraphic = cell.getGraphic();
    return cellGraphic;
}
```

Thank you Jai for pointing me in the right direction.